# Find the last cell column in table with Total Row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table that contains header row, data body and totals row.
I want to find the last row in the last column (in this case) of the data body and I want to have the value of the totals row.

[image: My Table with header row, data body and totals row]

I can get the last row and column value (135) by this VBA

```
Sub Target()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Worksheets("Nordics")
Dim ams As Long
Dim Target As Variant
ans = ws1.ListObjects("TableNordics").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count

Target = ws1.ListObjects("TableNordics").DataBodyRange(ans, 8).Value

End Sub
```

But, I can not get something simmilar to work for the Totals row (note, message box is just to see if the value works

```
Sub Table_Lastrow()

Dim ams As Long
ans = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableNordics").TotalsRowRange.Value
MsgBox "Last row in Table is  " & ans
End Sub
```

When I get this to work, I would like to change the Worksheet and Table name to be variable, eg. I will have the names in Cell A1 And A2, I have tried a couple of things for the first formula, but I can not get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to refer to the cell in the last column, which can be done using `.ListColumns.Count`:

```
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws1.ListObjects("TableNordics")

With tbl
    ans = .TotalsRowRange.Cells(.ListColumns.Count).Value
End With
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access the Total row values using the `ListObject.TotalsRowRange` property.  You need to ensure that the `ListObject.ShowTotals = True` to ensure to avoid a possible ***Object variable or With block variable not set*** error.

Personally I would use the `WorksheetFunction.Subtotal` (see `TargetAverage()`) to return the value.  In this way, you would not have to upate your code if the `TotalsRowRange` formula is changed.

```
Public Function wsNordics() As Worksheet
    Set wsNordics = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Nordics")
End Function

Public Function TableNordics() As ListObject
    Set TableNordics = wsNordics.ListObjects("TableNordics")
End Function

Public Function TargetAverage() As Double
    With TableNordics.ListColumns("Target")
        TargetAverage = WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(101, .DataBodyRange)
    End With
End Function

Public Function TableNordicsTargetAverage() As Double
    With TableNordics
        .ShowTotals = True
        With .TotalsRowRange
            TableNordicsTargetAverage = .Cells(, .Columns.Count)
        End With
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at this one if the person I have updated the workbook for is unsure how to use the Totals row I have now set!